# Implement poisson disk sampling in linear time

Tags: algorithm, poisson

I’m trying to implement the noise generator (Poisson disk noise) demonstrated [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/dbb02448b0f93e4c82c3) and described [here](http://devmag.org.za/2009/05/03/poisson-disk-sampling/), but I don’t know how to make it run in linear time due to the requirement that a *random* active sample (the red dots in the example) be popped from the active sample queue. As far as I can tell, this step itself has linear complexity since the sample isn’t popped from the end or dequeued from the beginning of the queue, making the whole algorithm quadratic.

How do I make the noise generator truly linear in time? As far as I can tell, this requires a sequence that a random element can be removed from in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the only operations you need to perform on this queue are to select and remove a random element, and to add new elements. In particular, you don't need to preserve order.

To implement this I would use a class supporting a variable length array, such as std::vector or java.util.ArrayList. To add an element, just add one on the end with push_back() or add(). To remove a random element, pick a random element within the array, save it, copy the element at the end of the array over element that you have just saved, and then reduce the size of the array by one. Something like

index = rng.nex()tInt(arr.size());

toReturn = arr.get(index);

arr.set(index, arr.get(arr.size() - 1));

arr.resize(arr.size() - 1);

return toReturn;

Comment: would it still work if I instead did the shuffling step when the element is *pushed* and then do all pops from the end?

Comment: I haven't gone into the details but I think it would be quite complicated to show that each element would always have the same probability of being chosen at random as before because if you do the shuffling early you don't know how many other elements will be put on in the future.